# PySpark JSON to DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have an API data set that is a nested JSON. But It doesn't have schema. This is the sample:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "hits": 20600
    },
    "data": {
        "2020-05-01": {
            "value": 20448,
            "data": {
                "neutral": {
                    "value": 11019
                },
                "positive": {
                    "value": 5866
                },
                "negative": {
                    "value": 3423
                },
                "unassigned": {
                    "value": 140
                }
            }
        },
        "2020-05-02": {
            "value": 152,
            "data": {
                "positive": {
                    "value": 73
                },
                "negative": {
                    "value": 42
                },
                "neutral": {
                    "value": 37
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using PySpark and I am able to read the data and create dataframe. But I am struggling to define schema and derive columns.

Ideally, I want to have tables with 3 columns:

- Event Date
- Event Type
- Event Number

I am saving the output as a JSON file and then create Dataframe

```
data_json = spark.read.json(json_file,multiLine=True)
display(data_json )
print(data_json .show())
```

It prints 2 columns `data` and `meta`. I want to `explode` column `data` with

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

explodeArrarDF = data_json.withColumn('Exp_RESULTS',F.explode(F.col('data'))).drop('data')
```

But it doesn't work. Error:

```
 cannot resolve 'explode(`data`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct<2020-05-01:struct<data:struct<negative:struct<value:bigint>,neutral:struct<value:bigint>,positive:struct<value:bigint>,unassigned:struct<value:bigint>>,value:bigint>,
```

I saw an example with creating of dataframe with `schema` option, but didn't have luck with it.

Comment: The error is clear,  column `data` is not an array but a struct. So use `col("data.*")` instead of explode.

Comment: Thank you, for suggestion. It is not clear what exactly to do. I tried:
```explodeArrarDF = synthesio_json.withColumn('Exp_RESULTS',F.col('data.*'))```
It didn't work.